# iTerm2 theme to mimic VS Code integrated terminal decoration style

Tags: visual-studio-code, terminal, styles, themes

I would like my iTerm2 have the circle line on the gutter (left) with the status of your executed commands, same as VS Code's integrated terminal's as follows:

[image]

The VS Code setting for this is `"terminal.integrated.shellIntegration.decorationIcon": "circle-outline"`

Is this possible? I'm currently using zsh with Oh-My-Zsh.